# How to save the client area of a child Window (MFC application) to an image

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, mfc

It's my first MFC application and I'm quite new to Visual Studio, so I can't understand exactly what I need to start with. I've already read many forums and MSDN articles, but I could not find the solution to my problem.

I have the source code of an old MFC application which you can find [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23111/Making-a-Class-Schedule-Using-a-Genetic-Algorithm). In short, this application takes a cfg file and using a genetic algorithm - makes a schedule for universities.

The problem is that the application does not have any kind of save-file possibility.

My task is to make all the required changes, so the application can save the final schedule to an image.

Maybe someone can tell me if what I want to do is possible and maybe I should start. Thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid this is much to broad for this website.  Try searching for "mfc save window image to bitmap".  First plausible looking hit is on [Codeguru](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/capturing/article.php/c4919/Capturing-a-Window-Image-Into-a-Bitmap-File-Supporting-MS-PaintBrush-and-All--Like-the-Thumbnail-View-of-Windows-Explorer.htm).  You probably want to work your way through the Scribble tutorial, and then come back here with *specific* questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, quite basic, but you have to start somewhere.

If all you want is somehow screen-capture your app's main (or any other) window using GDI here are the steps you need to take:

- Get the window's drawing surface (aka "canvas") using the `GetDC()` function (remember to release it when no longer needed, calling `ReleaseDC()`).
- Create a compatible **"memory Device Context"** and a **Bitmap**, which must be **"selected into"** the mem DC.
- Call the `BitBlt()` function. This will copy the graphics in the window DC to the mem DC. The bitmap which is selected into the mem DC will receive the graphic contents.
- Unselect the bitmap from the mem DC and delete the memDC.
- Then you need to save the bitmap to a file. The bitmap format is quite easy to save, basically it contains a header and the bitmap contents. There are GDI functions you can use to get both. Alternatively it can be sent to the Clipboard and pasted into a graphics processing program, like MsPaint.

The above guidelines are vague, but my intent here is to direct you where to look into, not provide a ready-made solution. You need to refer to the documentation to find details and functions. I would also suggest that you use the GDI-level functions instead of the MFC wrappers.

---

However, this is still quite a bit of work, and assuming that you have the source code and you can modify it, I wonder why not save the actual data as a comma- (or semicolon- or fixed-space) separated text file instead? It can be imported into Excel and processed, instead of saving just a screenshot, and the application not providing a file-save operation, doesn't prevent you adding one (or just a one-way-only one, aka "Export").

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast and detailed response. I have to say that your question sounds more interesting to me. But after searching different websites I did not found any possible way to redirect my canvas to a text file on a MFC GUI application. Is it possible? And if yes, do you know how?

Comment: I didn't mean send the graphics to a text file, this is impossible without OCR/ICR, and it would be an overkill. I meant print the actual data there (names, dates etc - simply convert them to text), without involving graphics at all.